# Chrome vs. Firefox Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a simple extension for Firefox. Unfortunately, my friend uses Chrome, and I don't understand why the same code does nothing in Chrome. What's the difference between Firefox's Tabs and Chrome's Tabs? Here's the code:

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "customAddon",
  "description": "Unsurprisingly, this addon does things.",
  "version": "1",
   "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["customAddon.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "http://*.com/"
   ]
}
```

customAddon.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId , info) {
    if (info.status == "complete") {
            if (window.location.href == 'http://ninjakiwi.com/Games/Action/Play/SAS-Zombie-Assault-4.html') {
                var elem = document.getElementById('secondary'); 
                elem.innerHTML = ''; 
                var removeLinks = (function() {
                    return function(passedElems){ 
                        for (i = 0; i < passedElems.length; i++) {
                            passedElems[i].setAttribute('onclick','return false;');
                        }}})(); 
                removeLinks(document.getElementsByClassName('group'));
                removeLinks(document.getElementsByClassName('nav'));
                removeLinks(document.getElementsByClassName('local-skin'));
                document.getElementsByClassName('header-bar')[0].setAttribute('style','padding-left:85px; padding-right:-85px;');}}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `customAddon.js` code runs is a separate, invisible page, called the background page.

Of course, its `location.href` will never be that URL, and its elements will never match what you expect.

What you really need is a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). You can set the filter that tells which page it should be loaded in, and then it will execute with access to the page's DOM, which is precisely what you need. No need to use `tabs` API.